# jQuery get json each is stacking strings instead of appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have a jQuery get that receives json five numbers. In the get I have an each function that should be appending to the original string instead it combines all of the data together. I have tried getJSON instead of get with a 'json' var at the end of the function. Any Ideas?

My '/?a=getrigs" JSON

```
[["50","81","82","85","86"]]
```

My jQuery:

```
var rigselect = "<select id='myid'>";
$.get("?a=getrigs", function(rigdata) {
    $.each(rigdata, function(rigkey, rigval) {
        rigselect += "<option value='" + rigval + "'>" + rigval + "</option>";
    });
    rigselect += "</select>";
}, "json");
```

what it generates:

```
<select id='myid'>
<option value="50,81,82,85,86">50,81,82,85,86</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to achieve and what the problem is. Keep in mind that the output you posted is an array and not a json

Comment: your json result is a nested array use `$.each(rigdata[0]...` or change your result and use $.getJSON

Comment: Are you sure, that rigval contains one value from the JSON? Can you try console.log(rigval)? See the results.

Comment: @Diego: A JSON value doesn't have to be an object, it can be an array, or even just a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON becomes an array of arrays when you deserialise it.

When you loop through the items in the outer array there will be only one item, which is an array. When you concatenate the array with strings the array will be converted to a string, which is the items in the array separated by commas.

Change the JSON to just an array:

```
["50","81","82","85","86"]
```

or loop through the inner array instead of the outer:

```
$.each(rigdata[0], function(rigkey, rigval) {
```